# Laravel Call to a member function respondToAccessTokenRequest() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel, I am trying to generate oauth token by extending Laravel Passport `AccessTokenController` class, and I always getting this error `"message": "Call to a member function respondToAccessTokenRequest() on null",`

here is my class

```
class B2BTokenController extends \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController
{
    function issueB2BToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        $req = $request->withParsedBody([
            "grant_type" => "client_credentials",
            "client_id" => $request->getHeaderLine('X-CLIENT-KEY'),
            "client_secret" => $request->getHeaderLine('X-SIGNATURE'),
        ]);


        $response = parent::issueToken($req);

        return $response->getContent();
    }
}
```

and here is `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController` class

```
class AccessTokenController
{
    use HandlesOAuthErrors;

    /**
     * The authorization server.
     *
     * @var \League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer
     */
    protected $server;

    /**
     * The token repository instance.
     *
     * @var \Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository
     */
    protected $tokens;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \League\OAuth2\Server\AuthorizationServer  $server
     * @param  \Laravel\Passport\TokenRepository  $tokens
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(AuthorizationServer $server,
                                TokenRepository $tokens)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
        $this->tokens = $tokens;
    }

    /**
     * Authorize a client to access the user's account.
     *
     * @param  \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        return $this->withErrorHandling(function () use ($request) {
            return $this->convertResponse(
                $this->server->respondToAccessTokenRequest($request, new Psr7Response)
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are overwriting the __construct method!
Check that and it will work